How can i fetch entities in JQPL correct?
I have Java Spring 4 entities with that structure:
 EntityA {
    
        @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
        EntityB b1;
        @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
        EntityB b2;
    }

EntityB {

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade=ALL)
    List<EntityC> c1;
}

EntityC {
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    EntityD d1;
}

EntityD {
    Boolean disable;
}

I tried to get HQL request like this:
@Query(value = """
        select a from EntityA a
        join fetch a.b1 ab1
        join fetch a.b2 ab2
        """)
        

In debug i see that i get from DB fetching all values before d1. d1 get from HibernateProxy.
How can i improve my request for getting only EntitiesC where d1.disable = false?

You don't need to write an explicit query for this, but you can use a query derived from method name, inside a Repository interface; in the method name you can tell hibernate to add a where clause on joined tables with underscores.
The repository for EntityA should be like this:
@Repository
public interface EntityARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, YourIdType>{
    List<EntityA> findByB1_C1_D1DisableFalse();
}

This way at the end of the query there will be where d1.disable = false
